# undefined method `abs' but isnt absolute a function in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I tried to call `abs` for my math in the code but the terminal reports that abs is unidentified when it is supposed to be in the language itself.
The error message: `customcode.rb:58:in <class:Survivor>: undefined method abs for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

```
        vel_sum = (@vel_x).abs + (@vel_y).abs\r
                          ^^^^
```

This is the part of the code where the error lies

```
  def acceleration(direction)
            case direction
                when :forwards  
                    @vel_x += Math.sin(@sprite.rotate*Math::PI/180) 
                    @vel_y -= Math.cos(@sprite.rotate*Math::PI/180) 
                when :backwards  
                    @vel_x -= Math.sin(@sprite.rotate*Math::PI/180) 
                    @vel_y += Math.cos(@sprite.rotate*Math::PI/180) 
            end
        end

            vel_sum = @vel_x.abs + @vel_y.abs
        if vel_sum > 2
            @vel_x = @vel_x*2
            @vel_y = @vel_y*2
        end
```

`vel_sum = @vel_x.abs + @vel_y.abs`
@vel_x and y should be integers so I honestly do not know why It does not work. I hope some passerby could help me with this one.

Comment: What version of Ruby? Is it definitely pointing to that line? Can you post the entire error message? `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` do not return integers but still inherit from Numeric so it `abs` should be valid.

Comment: Tangential, but they’re unlikely to be integers at that point. What is the *exact* error? The exact error output should be included in the question.

Comment: My apologies lads/gentlemen, I have updated the full error message in the post

Comment: It's not complaining about `abs` not being a method, it's complaining about it not being a method on `nil`. Either @vel_x or @vel_y is nil. My guess is both. You have a case statement with no default; what if the direction is neither?

Comment: The main code was fully functional until I added in the `      vel_sum = @vel_x.abs + @vel_y.abs
        if vel_sum > 2
            @vel_x = @vel_x*2
            @vel_y = @vel_y*2
        end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vel_sum...` code is outside of the `def acceleration` method, therefore the program does not understand @vel_x and @vel_y when it is called.

```
def acceleration(direction)
            case direction
                when :forwards  
                    @vel_x += Math.sin(@sprite.rotate*Math::PI/180) 
                    @vel_y -= Math.cos(@sprite.rotate*Math::PI/180) 
                when :backwards  
                    @vel_x -= Math.sin(@sprite.rotate*Math::PI/180) 
                    @vel_y += Math.cos(@sprite.rotate*Math::PI/180) 
            end

            vel_sum = @vel_x.abs + @vel_y.abs
            if vel_sum > 2
                @vel_x = @vel_x*(2/vel_sum)
                @vel_y = @vel_y*(2/vel_sum)
            end
end
```

This fix should work..